# "contains" filter on json_query keeps returning all data instead of what is specific in the filter

Tags: ansible, json-query

I have the following data that I'm trying to filter:

```
      "flags": [
        "inhibitor"
      ],
......(some data here)....
      "flags": [],
......(some other data here)...
      "flags": [],
```

The code below is supposed to filter through the data above and return only those "flags" that has the string "inhibitor" such that it should return:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [ "inhibitor" ]
    ]
}
```

But instead, it returns all the "flags" including the empty ones:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "inhibitor"
        ],
        [],
        []
    ]
}
```

```
  - name: Set appropriate facts based on the report
    set_fact:
      leapp_preupgrade_report_inhibitors: >
        {{ leapp_preupgrade_report["entries"] | json_query("[*].flags[?contains(@, 'inhibitor')]") | list }}

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ leapp_preupgrade_report_inhibitors }}"
```

I have also tried the following iteration, to no avail:

```
{{ leapp_preupgrade_report["entries"] | to_json |from_json | json_query("[*].flags[?contains(@, 'inhibitor')]") | list }}
```

How should I properly filter the data that I need to get a list of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the data

```yaml
  report:
    entries:
      - flags: [inhibitor]
      - flags: []
      - flags: []
```

the query below does the job

```yaml
  inhibitors: "{{ report.entries|
                  json_query('[?contains(flags, `inhibitor`)]') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  inhibitors:
    - flags: [inhibitor]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    report:
      entries:
        - flags: [inhibitor]
        - flags: []
        - flags: []

    inhibitors: "{{ report.entries|
                    json_query('[?contains(flags, `inhibitor`)]') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: inhibitors
```

---

The filter *selectattr* and the Ansible test [*contains*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-if-a-list-contains-a-value) give the same result

```yaml
  inhibitors: "{{ report.entries|
                  selectattr('flags', 'contains', 'inhibitor') }}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That gave me the output I needed.